# What is the best way to check correct dtypes in a pandas dataframe as part of testing?

Tags: python, pandas, testing, types, series

Before pre-processing and training a model on some data, I want to check that each feature (each column) of a dataframe is of the correct data type. i.e. if a dataframe has columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, they should have types `int`, `float`, `string` respectively as I have defined them (`col1` can't be of type `string`, the order matters).

What is the best way to do this if

1. The columns have various types - int, float, timestamp, string
2. There are too many columns (>500) to manually write out / label each column data type

Something like

```
types = df.dtypes # returns a pandas series
if types != correct_types:
    raise TypeError("Some of the columns do not have the correct type")
```

Where `correct_types` are the known data types of each column - these would need to be in the same order as `types` to ensure each column type is correctly matched. It would also be good to know which column is throwing the error (so maybe a for loop over the columns is more appropriate?)

Is there any way to achieve this, and if so what is the best way to achieve this? Maybe I am looking at the issue the wrong way - more generally, how do I ensure that the columns of `df` are of the correct data type as I have defined them?

Comment: How looks `correct_types` ? It is `Series`? `dict` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) to return a series mapping column name to data type:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, True, 'dsfasd', 51.314],
                   [51, False, '56345', 56.1234]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])

res = df.dtypes

print(res)

col1      int64
col2       bool
col3     object
col4    float64
dtype: object
```

The values of this series are `dtype` objects:

```
print(res.iloc[0])

dtype('int64')
```

As a series, you can filter by index or by value. For example, to filter for `int64` type:

```
print(res[res == np.dtype('int64')])

col1    int64
dtype: object
```

You can also compare the series to another via `series1 == series2` to create a Boolean series mapping. A trivial example checking the series with itself:

```
# in reality, you will check res versus a custom series_valid
print(res == res)

col1    True
col2    True
col3    True
col4    True
dtype: bool
```

If any values in your comparison is `False`, you can raise an error:

```
if (res != series_valid).any():
    indices = (res != series_valid).index.tolist()
    raise TypeError("Some columns have incorrect type: {0}".format(indices))
```